# Why getting this error: The app you are using is not responding. Please try again later

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebook credits but I got this error:

**"The app you are using is not responding. Please try again later."**

I don't know what is the reason for that,

I looked at the firebug console and see some long requests that take something like 40 sec, the requests targets is: **http://0-if-w.channel.facebook.com/pull?channel=p_685255507&seq=3&clientid=25523dd1&cb=gcgh&idle=41&state=active**

Does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Facebook Credits Demo Application</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="yosi" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="game" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost/ff_without/Facebook/default.aspx" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://apps.facebook.com/yositestmylife/Media/Images/credit.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="life2d0001" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="685000507" />
     <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Facebook Credits Demo Application</h2>
    <p>
        Create an order by specifying the following attributes:</br> <i>Title, price, description,
            image URL and product URL</i></p>
    <!-- Please note that user can change any information in order_info through 
    javascript. So please make sure you never put price or any other 
    information you don't want users to modify in order_info. We put everything
    here only for end-to-end flow testing purpose!! -->
    <form name="place_order" id="order_form" action="#">
    Title:
    <input type="text" name="title" value="BFF Locket" id="title_el" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Price:
    <input type="text" name="price" value="10" id="price_el" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Description:
    <input type="text" name="description" size="64" value="This is a BFF Locket..." id="desc_el" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Image URL:
    <input type="text" name="image_url" size="64" value="http://localhost/ff_without/media/images/credit.png"
        id="img_el" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Product URL:
    <input type="text" name="product_url" size="64" value="http://localhost/ff_without/facebook/Credit_buy.aspx"
        id="product_el" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a onclick="placeOrder(); return false;">
        <img src="http://www.facebook.com/connect/button.php?app_id=<%=appID%>&feature=payments&type=light_l">
    </a>
    </form>
    <div id="output">
        <%=htmlResponse%>
    </div>
    <br/><br/> 
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({appId: <%=appID%>, status: true, cookie: true});

    function placeOrder() {
      var title = document.getElementById('title_el').value;
      var desc = document.getElementById('desc_el').value;
      var price = document.getElementById('price_el').value;
      var img_url = document.getElementById('img_el').value;
      var product_url = document.getElementById('product_el').value;

      // Only send param data for sample. These parameters should be set
      // in the callback.
      var order_info = { "title":title,
                         "description":desc,
                         "price":price,
                         "image_url":img_url,
                         "product_url":product_url
                       };

      // calling the API ...
//      var obj = {
//      method: 'pay',
//      order_info: order_info,
//      purchase_type: 'item'
//      };
        var obj = {
          method: 'pay',
          order_info: order_info,
          purchase_type: 'item',
          dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}
        };
      FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }

    var callback = function(data) {
    //alert('ghg');
      if (data['order_id']) {
        writeback("Transaction Completed! </br></br>"
        + "Data returned from Facebook: </br>"
        + "<b>Order ID: </b>" + data['order_id'] + "</br>"
        + "<b>Status: </b>" + data['status']);
      } else if (data['error_code']) {
        writeback("Transaction Failed! </br></br>"
        + "Error message returned from Facebook:</br>"
        + data['error_message']);
      } else {
        writeback("Transaction failed!");
      }
    };

    function writeback(str) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=str;
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

//changed the encoding of the callback page.
If your callback page is encoded in UTF-8, check that it is UTF-8 without BOM.

I think this thread states solution to your problem. Hope it helps:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90781

Answer (score 1):

this may be because of

- the maximum execution time for your files is less
- This error occurs when your server ([callback url)](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90781) does not send the response back in correct JSON format. Please make sure the responses are *exactly* in these formats and everything should work fine
- or the server you are requested may be faced with down time.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the callback.php sample from Facebook Docs then comment out like 26, 32 and line 44.

this will end the error in that case.

---

```
 // if ($item_id == '1a') {
    $item = array(
      'title' => '100 some game cash',
      'description' => 'Spend cash in some game.',
      // Price must be denominated in credits.
      'price' => 10,
      //'image_url' => 'http://some_image_url/coin.jpg',
    );

    // Construct response.
    $response = array(
                  'content' => array(
                                 0 => $item,
                               ),
                  'method' => $request_type,
                );
    // Response must be JSON encoded.
    $response = json_encode($response);
  //}
```